# Has the weather been affected by the moons increasing distance from Earth?

Tags: the-moon, weather, earth

The moon moves approximately 4cm away from Earth per year.

Given that it affects Earth's weather, will this increasing distance already have had an impact on the weather (regardless of how negligible this difference is)?

Comment: I don't think this question is in scope here, but looks like a good question for the proposed site [Scientific Imagination](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination)